# Reordering items in a QTreeWidget with Drag and Drop in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, qtreewidget

I have a QTreeWidget with what I thought all the proper settings setup in order to be able to reorder items by dragging them around. It can work, at times, but more often than not I drag an item into another one and it either disappears or becomes a child.

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening so you don't lose items you're trying to reorder? I figured you could achieve this within Qt Designer. I have **dragDrop** mode set to InternalMove and **defaultDropAction** set to MoveAction, but I'm not even certain of both of those are what I need to be adjusting.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can add flags to individual tree widget items that control drag and drop behaviour (amongst other things). For instance, to prevent an item being a drop target, try something like this:

```
item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
item.setFlags(items.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)
```

For more details, see: [Qt.ItemFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum)